# VW unit, sizes attribute and media queries do not work

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have been learning responsive images lately but I've struggling with the VW unit and the sizes attribute. Down I'll post an example but I tried a lot of variants even adding media queries or loading the page on Firefox, I simply don't get it.

I want, for example, an image to reduce to half the size of the viewport when the windows is larger than 800px.

Do I have to use precise CSS code or I can do it just using HTML? Doesn't the sizes attribute change an image even on his own?

```html
<img src="Images/large.jpg" 
     sizes="50vw" >
```

Comment: You can use CSS for all that - look in to max-wdith and min-wdth https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Comment: I figured  should learn CSS but then what if I want to use sizes and srcset??

Answer (score 0):

Set the "mobile" width outside of the media query, then set the media query to `min-width: 800px`:

```css
#img{
    width: 200px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
    #img{
        width: 50vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/500/500" id="img">
```

Comment: So what’s sizes for? I’ve seen a couple of example using it to have different sizes depending on the window width

Comment: It's a way to embed the style rules in the element itself. It's easier to just write media queries.

Comment: I really can’t do it only with sizes? With no CSS, a lot of example gave it for a given then?